# toggling class dynamically in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am working on a React application that has a header component with two buttons:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className='header'>
      <h2 className='resume-title'>
        Muhammad <br />
        Sohaib Furqan
      </h2>
      <button className='btn'>
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
      </button>
      <button className='btn'>
        <Link to='/projects'>Projects</Link>
      </button>
    </header>
  );
};
```

I want to make it so that the button that is clicked gets the 'active' class while the other buttons the 'active' class is removed. In vanillaJS, I would use 'querySelectorAll' to get all buttons and then map through the nodeList, toggling as appropriate. But not sure how I would do that in React. I'm inclined towards useRef but how can I set ref to point to the button that was clicked?

Hope I've managed to make myself clear.

TIA,
Sohaib

Comment: Remove Button and add btn class to Link. Then handle activeClassName.

Comment: You can just use `NavLink` component from `react-router-dom`. It gets a class `.active` when the path matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink).

You can use it like

```
<NavLink className="btn" to='/'>Home</Link>
```

NavLink will get `.active` class when path matches. So you can add styles to the `active` class.

You can also customize the className using

```
<NavLink to="/" activeClassName="some-custom-class">
 Home
</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Link>` no longer has the `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` properties. In `react-router v4` you have to use `<NavLink>` if you want to do conditional styling:

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header className='header'>
      <h2 className='resume-title'>
        Muhammad <br />
        Sohaib Furqan
      </h2>
      <NavLink to='/' className="btn" activeClassName="active">Home</Link>
      <NavLink to='/projects' className="btn" activeClassName="active">Projects</Link>
    </header>
  );
};
```

and in your `style.css`

```
.active { //do-whatever }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Header = () => {
  const [active,setActive] = useState("Home")
  const handleActive = (activeTab) => {
     setActive(activeTab)
  }
  return (
    <header className='header'>
      <h2 className='resume-title'>
        Muhammad <br />
        Sohaib Furqan
      </h2>
      <button className={active === "Home" ? 'btn active' : 'btn' } onClick={() => handleActive("Home")} >
        <Link to='/'>Home</Link>
      </button>
      <button className={active === "Projects" ? 'btn active' : 'btn' } onClick={() => handleActive("Projects")} >
        <Link to='/projects'>Projects</Link>
      </button>
    </header>
  );
};
```